# 422 Client Error: Unknown Error Soundcloud API Track Upload

Tags: python, soundcloud

Having some problems uploading a track using the [soundcloud](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python) python library to interact with the Soundcloud api.

Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploadToSoundcloud.py", line 25, in <module>
    'asset_data': open('/home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_'+now.strftime("%y%m%d")+'.mp3', 'rb')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/client.py", line 130, in _request
    return wrapped_resource(make_request(method, url, kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/soundcloud/request.py", line 134, in make_request
    result.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 722, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.422 Client Error: Unknown Error
```

Code causing error. Line 25 refers to the assest_data line.

```
#Upload driveAtFive to SoundCloud
driveAtFive = client.post('/tracks', driveAtFive={
    'title': 'Drive at 5 - ' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    'sharing': 'public',
    'asset_data': open('/home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_'+now.strftime("%y%m%d")+'.mp3', 'rb')
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `track` keyword argument. Here you've named it `driveAtFive` which is incorrect. Change the code example to this:

```
driveAtFive = client.post('/tracks', track={
  'title': 'Drive at 5 - ' + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
  'sharing': 'public',
  'asset_data': open('/home/jhvisser/Music/driveAt5_'+now.strftime("%y%m%d")+'.mp3', 'rb')
})
```

Let me know if that helps.